# Why does this function variable have initial values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

When I log arr early in this function, it has values (shown below). I expected it to print [[null,null],[null,null]]; instead, it prints the value of arr that results once this function finishes.

```
  updateBounds() {
    let arr = [Array(2), Array(2)];
    console.log('initial value')
    console.log(arr);
    arr[0][0] = this.state.homePoint.geometry.coordinates[0];
    arr[1][0] = this.state.homePoint.geometry.coordinates[0];
    arr[0][1] = this.state.homePoint.geometry.coordinates[1];
    arr[1][1] = this.state.homePoint.geometry.coordinates[1];
    this.state.points.forEach(p => {
      if (p.geometry) {
        if (p.geometry.coordinates) {
          arr[0][0] = Math.min(p.geometry.coordinates[0], arr[0][0]);
          arr[1][0] = Math.max(p.geometry.coordinates[0], arr[1][0]);
          arr[0][1] = Math.min(p.geometry.coordinates[1], arr[0][1]);
          arr[1][1] = Math.max(p.geometry.coordinates[1], arr[1][1]);
        }
      }
    });
    this.setState({bounds: arr});
  }
```

resulting console output:

```
initial value
App.js:444 (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) [-122.438227, 37.742017]
1: (2) [-122.40766, 37.784995]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `Object.assign({},arr))` will create a new object copying things from `arr`, so it's normal when you log both that they'd look the same. The object created is immediately discarded, though.

Comment: what are your trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm assuming you want a shallow copy of the array. In that case you can use: `arr = Array.from(arr);`

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed somewhat surprising... the problem is that when you call `log` the browser takes note of the objects but not of their content (at the time of the log call).

If you want to see objects content at the time of the call then use `console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` instead.

Comment: thank you! I used console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)) and that printed my object as expected

Answer (score 1):

[Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. **If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.**

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "slice" not "splice"

Comment: @astrojams1 try replacing it in your code and update the question